# How to get specific columns from relation table in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to fetch soecific columns data from relational table but it is giving me null

```
$allConsignments = Consignment::query();
$allConsignments->select(['id','customer_reference'])->with('customers:name,id')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(5000)->get();
```

When I don't use `select()` then it gives correct data .

like this

```
$allConsignments = Consignment::query();
$allConsignments->with('customers:name,id')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(5000)->get()
```

it is working but I also need specific columns from `Consignment` Table. what could be the reason?

Comment: delete the `select()`, make your query on get() as `get(['id','customer_reference'])`

Comment: i tried it but not working

Comment: Provide your related models and migrations for these tables

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this.

`$allConsignments = Consignment::query();`

`$allConsignments::with('customers:name,id')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(5000)->get(['id','customer_reference']);`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I also need to select the foreign key column from the table on which relationship is based. for example in my case I have `customer_id` in consignment table so it should be like that

```
$allConsignments = Consignment::query();
$allConsignments->select('id','customer_reference','customer_id')->with('customers:name,id')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(5000)->get();
```

I need to select `customer_id` as well